# How to add dpi responsive images to android studio?

Tags: java, android, image, uiimageasset

I am new to the android development environment. I want to add an image into my application but with different dpi. If I go to drawable > new > Image Asset I can only add an icon for my app/menu button/notification icon. If I select the launcher icon, my image becomes way too small. If I click the menu bar menu, it becomes white. If I click notification, they're as tiny as an ant. Anyways, I was wondering if I can make android studio make the image responsive by adding differing dpis. like splash.png   *HDPI*
                     splash.png   *MDPI*
See what I mean? I made a splashscreen but on different devices it's either too small/too big.

**Note: PARDON ME IF THIS HAS BEEN ASKED BEFORE. I AM KINDA NEW**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your res folder there multiple folders for drawables
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
...

if you want to add an image for hdpi devices add it into drawable-hdpi

Comment: Don't have those folders, using AS (Android Studio). I only have drawable.  Unless I change to "project" then I view those folders. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio doesn't create folders for different dpi's by default. So, you will need to create those folders yourself and add images to it. Just create folders such as drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, and if you need drawable-xhdpi and so on.

If you are using Eclipse then those folders are created by IDE itself.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: It does, It just makesyou view it in a much simpler way. Change Android to "project" and you'll see it in the eclipse way (What I call it: Confusing directories)

Comment: I think it doesn't show you drawbale-hdpi folders. I guess, the folders that you see are mipmap-hdpi and so on. This are specifically for placing app icons, I suppose.

Comment: For more information you can refer [developers-blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html).